# Suddenly Visual Studio now builds and deploys EVERYTHING

Tags: visual-studio

I've been using Visual Studio for years. When I press F5 or Ctrl+F5, or press the green arrow button, I expect it to build and run the Startup Project and its dependencies. However, suddenly today it builds (and deploys to the mobile device, if it's a mobile device solution) every single project instead.

I tried several different sln files, same thing happens for each one.

Also, while the debugger works in desktop projects, in mobile projects it simply states "unable to start debugging".

Anybody else had this problem?

I found one workaround, to right-click a single project and choose Debug | Start New Instance. (However, there is no option to start without debugging.)

Comment: Is there anything untoward happening in the Configuration Manager? Sometimes I find VS forgets something, and chooses to build all my projects.

Comment: No, but I agree, VS does occasionally "randomize" some of the settings in Configuration Manager :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which version of Visual Studio you are using.

In Visual Studio 2010 take a look at Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Build and Run | "Only build Startup projects and dependencies on Run".  Is that item checked?

Comment: Oh, I'm on VS 2008, but it has the same option. That fixes the problem, thanks! (debugger's not fixed, I guess it's unrelated.)